# RayCasting picture noise render method

Tags: 3d, rendering, raycasting

I'm creating a RayCasting tutorial on github (click [here](https://github.com/vinibiavatti1/RayCastingTutorial/wiki) to access it) and I'm following a lot of tutorials, implementations and other render methods in the web. One game made with it is the "Prelude of the Chambered" by Markus Persson. He made this game in 2 days with native programming.

My question is about the noise picture effect he used for rendering. I wanted to know how to do this, and if this has some render name. Check the image bellow and you will know what I'm speaking about:

[image]

If you check some render position you will find some noise pixels. What is the method to do this? This techique has some name?

[image]

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: This looks like dithering. Is that possibly what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes of course! I've already checked it before, but for rendering, is there some technique or logic to make it? I'll search in the web about it to try to discover something... Thanks!

Comment: See [Ordered Dithering - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IviNO7iICTM) and [Error Diffusion Dithering - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ico4fJfohMQ).